# Windows Server 2012 R2 - NAT for Hyper-V Internal switch

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, nat

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 box, and am migrating some Hyper-V VMs over to this machine. I'm trying to use the NAT feature from the Routing and Remote Access role to give a Hyper-V Internal switch, and the VMs connected to that switch, internet access.

The box has one internet facing NIC, which has several public IP addresses assigned to it. My end goal is to map a specific IP currently on the internet facing NIC of the host to a VM attached to the Hyper-V Internal switch.

Let's say that the internet facing switch has 3 IP addresses assigned:

- 1.1.1.1
- 2.2.2.2
- 3.3.3.3

I have enabled the Routing and Remote Access role.

I currently have a static IP set for the Hyper-V internal switch device, which is: 192.168.0.1. I'm trying to configure the system so any VM attached to this switch will receive an IP address within the 192.168.0.10-192.168.0.100 range.

Within the Routing and Remote Access configuration window, I've set the 'Address Assignment' tab of NAT properties to automatically assign IP addresses by using the DHCP allocator, and set the IP address to 192.168.0.0 and mask to 255.255.255.0.

I have added two interfaces to the NAT section - one is the internet facing physical device on the host, the other is the Hyper-V Internal switch. For the internet facing switch, in the properties window I've set the Interface Type to public, and enabled NAT on this interface. For the Hyper-V Internal switch, I've set the Interface Type to Private.

When I bring up a VM attached to the switch, and attempt to get an IP address via DHCP, I don't get a response. I'm not sure where I went wrong with my configuration - according to most of the guides I've read and followed it should be working. Any ideas?